# AWS AutoScaling Policy CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I am making a very simple request, and I keep getting a Validation Error and can't figure out what is going wrong..

```
~ aws autoscaling put-scaling-policy --auto-scaling-group-name MY_GROUP --policy-name KILL-TWO-SERVERS --adjustment-type ChangeInCapacity --adjustment=-2

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the PutScalingPolicy operation: Valid adjustment types are: [PercentChangeInCapacity, ChangeInCapacity, ExactCapacity].
```

I have even tried copy and pasting "ChangeInCapacity" to make sure there is no error.  Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
aws autoscaling put-scaling-policy --auto-scaling-group-name MY_GROUP --policy-name KILL-TWO-SERVERS --adjustment-type ChangeInCapacity --scaling-adjustment -2
```